# bind_param with array$i php database

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I'm trying to insert data from an array into my database. I found few people that had similar problems so it could be duplicate, but the answers didn't help me at all, because they didn't have the `$i` variable in the code. So could you please help me insert these values to my database?

```
 for ($i=0; $i < $_SESSION["count"]; $i++) {

   // Create connection
   $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
   // Check connection
   if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
   }
     $stmt = ("INSERT INTO dite (name, lname, adress, bday, inf1, inf2, inf3, id_o, id_m, id_p) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);");
     $stmt->bind_param("sssssssiii",$_SESSION["name$i"], $_SESSION["lname$i"],
                      $_SESSION["adress$i"], $_SESSION["bday$i"],
                      $_SESSION["inf1$i"], $_SESSION["inf1$i"],
                      $id_o, $id_m, $id_p);
     $stmt->execute();
     printf("%d Row inserted.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);
     $stmt->close();

     $conn->close();
 }
```

Every help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

If I did `echo loop` on every session I would get this:

```
test_name0 
test_lname0
test_address0
test_bday0
test_inf10
test_inf20
        //(blank)


test_name1 
test_lname1
test_address1
test_bday1
test_inf11
                 //(blank)
asdfg1

and $id_o = 0; $id_m = 0; $id_p = 0;
```

And error looks like this:

> Call to a member function bind_param() on string in C:\wamp64\www\login\file.php on line 210.

Line 210 is:

```
$stmt->bind_param("sssssssiii",$_SESSION["name$i"], $_SESSION["lname$i"],
```

Comment: Can you show us what data is in your session? I'd also move your DB connection and close stuff outside the loop as you're making connections and closing it every time the loop iterates.

Comment: data in session are in edit above, i tried to move DB connection and close outside the loop but the error stays the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> prepare and bind.

in your query you are just binding, without preparing.

```
<?php

    for ($i=0; $i < $_SESSION["count"]; $i++) {

       // Create connection
       $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
       // Check connection
       if ($conn->connect_error) {
          die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
       }
         $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO dite (name, lname, adress, bday, inf1, inf2, inf3, id_o, id_m, id_p) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);");
         $stmt->bind_param("sssssssiii",$_SESSION["name$i"], $_SESSION["lname$i"],
                          $_SESSION["adress$i"], $_SESSION["bday$i"],
                          $_SESSION["inf1$i"], $_SESSION["inf1$i"],
                          $id_o, $id_m, $id_p);
         $stmt->execute();
         printf("%d Row inserted.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);
         $stmt->close();

         $conn->close();
     }
     ?>
```